# ReboundPanel Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

The happy face Im using----)[image: Happyface.gif]This project wants me to Modify the Rebound program from this chapter such that when the mouse button is clicked the animation stops, and when its clicked again the animation resumes.
When I click on the screen with the moving smiley face, it doesnt stop when I click it nor start up again because I couldnt stop the smiley face from moving  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the problem area.------) |

```
private class ReboundMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (timer.isRunning())
            timer.stop();
        else
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
}
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
public class ReboundPanel extends JPanel {
    private final int WIDTH =300, HEIGHT= 100;
    private final int DELAY= 20, IMAGE_SIZE=35;

    private ImageIcon image;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x, y, moveX, moveY;

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    //  Sets up the panel,including the timer for the animation.
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    public ReboundPanel(){
        timer= new Timer(DELAY, new ReboundListener());
        image= new ImageIcon("happyFace.gif");

        x=0;
        y=40;
        moveX=moveY=3;

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        timer.start();
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    //  Draws the image in the current location.
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        image.paintIcon(this, page, x, y);
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //  Represents the action listener for the timer.
    //*********************************************************
    private class ReboundListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------
        //  Updates the position of the image and possibly the direction
        //  of movement whenever the timer fires an action event.
        //--------------------------------------------------------
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            x += moveX;
            y += moveY;

            if (x <=0 || x >= WIDTH-IMAGE_SIZE)
                moveX =moveX * -1;

            if (y <=0 || y >= HEIGHT-IMAGE_SIZE)
                moveY = moveY * -1;

            repaint();      
        }
    }

    private class ReboundMouseListener implements MouseListener {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Stops or starts the timer (and therefore the animation)
        //  when the mouse button is clicked.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            if (timer.isRunning())
                timer.stop();
            else
                timer.start();
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Provide empty definitions for unused event methods.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Rebound {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rebound");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ReboundPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can't get your programme to start, how can you try to stop it? What exactly do you mean with 'you can neither start nor stop the programme'? Please be specific in as what steps you take and where it fails with what error exactly. Edit your question as required.

Comment: When I click on the screen with the moving smiley face. It doesnt stop when I click it nor start up again because I couldnt stop the smiley face from moving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing your `addMouseListener()` calls:

```
public ReboundPanel() {
    // Other initializations ...

    addMouseListener(new ReboundMouseListener());    // <-- add

    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: When I add the code it says this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 ReboundMouseListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I think your `ReboundMouseListener` was inside your `ReboundListener` class, and was accidentally moved out during the formatting.  Make the same "accident" happen to your code, and the `ReboundMouseListener` class should be found.

Comment: Thanks for the help it fixed the problem. I appreciate it.